# Maximum and minimum value of an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Hello during a problem I have to solve this with $a,b,c$ positiv real number:
$$6\geq\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}+\frac{c^2 + c b + 2 b + b^2 + 3}{c^2 + c b - 2 b + b^2 + 3}+\frac{a^2 + a c + 2 c + c^2 + 3}{a^2 + a c - 2 c + c^2 + 3}\geq 3$$
Edit:Wolfram alpha says that the minimum value is 3.

Second edit :This is what I want to solve :

> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{a + \sqrt{a b} + 2 \sqrt{a} + b + 3}{a + \sqrt{a b}- 2 \sqrt{a} + b + 3}$$

I try many classical inequalities , but without success .

Thanks a lot .

Comment: Hint: for all three terms,  the denominator is positive and the numerator is greater than it. this give you an lower bound. Can you find a way to approach this lower bound?

Comment: Yes I understand many thanks !

Comment: @achille hui Very nice solution!

Comment: @FatsWallers I solved your problem. Why did you change the problem? You can open another topic for this. I think it's not fair!

Comment: Please refrain from changing the question once an answer has been provided. *Chamaleon questions* should be avoidedat all costs, since they tend to waste the efforts (and time) of users. Please use separate questions for different separate things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first inequality is wrong take $a=\frac{1}{1000}$ and $a=b=1.5$

It's more than 6 .

Answer (score 0):

The inequality

> $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2 + a b + 2 a + b^2 + 3}{a^2 + a b - 2 a + b^2 + 3}\leq \sum_{cyc}\frac{a + \sqrt{a b} + 2 \sqrt{a} + b + 3}{a + \sqrt{a b}- 2 \sqrt{a} + b + 3}.$$

is wrong.

Try $b=c\rightarrow0^+$ and $a=1.1$.